# How to know value in the std::string/Cstring is number or not

Tags: c++, mfc

I am getting command line argument when i launch the application.
I am getting four parameter from command line.

after parsing I store them in four std::string/CString(mfc)  variable now i need to know whether the value is decimal or not.because these parameter is going to be used in some mathematical calculation.

Can anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#C.2B.2B) you can find how to determine if a string is a numeric, in 70 languages!

I'm not sure if all the solutions check the same thing. The C++ implementation checks if the input is a positive/negative integer/floating-point for base 10, or if it a is positive/negative integer for base 8/16. **Is that what you want? Do you need to support only positive numbers? Do you need to support floating-points?**

Probably you'll need to convert your input strings to numeric value, so there is no reason to do it in two steps (to check, then to convert). Better do it in a single step.

One more thing: If the input string is too long, for example "32525252332912461984612491264912649126129319312931279171295127951275129" - you normally won't want to consider it as a valid input.

Comment: Oooh, nice one. For those who haven't followed the link yet, by "70 languages" he means computer languages, not human ones.

Answer (score 2):

Look at every character in the string, and if you find something that is not a digit, or a '.', then it is not a number.

Comment: Fail: "0.1.2.3" passes the test but is not a valid number.

Comment: Yeah, you would need some sort of counter to make sure there is only 0 or 1 `.`

Comment: Just trying to give Chris ideas, not do it for him.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a string->number conversion function that unambiguously reports failure.

e.g. `strtod` and not `atof`